# What does this mutation notation mean: MAP2K41161fs*12

Tags: mutations, gene

I received a report that had a mutation notated as: "MAP2K41161fs*12". I'm used to seeing this sort of thing: BRAF(V600E) or BRAF(T1799TA). Can someone tell me how to interpret "MAP2K41161fs*12" ?? Is it a deletion? An insertion? A translocation? Or What?

Comment: Can you post a link to the paper? MAP2K is the protein. fs means frame shift and *12 gives the length of the new reading frame (ie the number of codons up to and including new stop codon). Usually before fs they give the first mutated amino acid, so I'm not sure what the number 41161 means (no protein is that long).

Comment: Or the protein is MAP2K4 and the number is 1161, but I still don't know what that means since MAP2K4 is 399 aa…

Comment: Oh my....duh! Of course I should have figured out that "fs" means frameshift. But I'm used to seeing just the ins or del. I've now looked at a couple of online pages describing this notation, but they refer to the length of the new reading frame (just as you did). This seems like an odd thing to provide...doesn't the new reading frame go on until the next stop codon or complementary indel? And you'd have to provide the terminal event (X or indel) anyway, right? Weird. Anyway, thanks! I can figure out the rest from this hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fs means frame shift and *12 gives the length of the new reading frame (ie the number of codons up to and including new stop codon). Usually before fs they give the first mutated amino acid, so I'm not sure what the number 41161 means (but apparently the OP does).